# using bulma icon but can not display to the screen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulma

I am newbie with Bulma and trying to show an icon by this way.
I download the code from internet and tried to run it, here is my code

```
<nav class="level">
<div class="level-left">
<a class="button is-medium is-facebook">
<span class="icon">
<i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
</span>
</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

very easy to understand, right ? but it did not display the icon as you can see here [picture about this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAxg0.png).
Could you please give me some ideas ? By the way, I used Rails to code too. I also install bulma to my computer by yarn. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Bulma icon, that's a Font Awesome icon. In order to use it, you need to add Font Awesome. You can [use CDN](https://fontawesome.com/start) and add it to the head section of your app or install it with [yarn](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers).